# What does the word "that" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

> There is a major objection to the argument from Fine Tuning. Imagine
> that you have bought a ticket for a national lottery. There are,
> perhaps, many millions of tickets, but only one will win. It is
> statistically highly unlikely that you will win. But you might. If you
> do, however, this doesn’t demonstrate more than your good luck: it
> doesn’t follow from the fact that, from amongst all those millions of
> losing tickets, your winning ticket was chosen **that** this must have
> been the result of something more than a random selection.

[Philosophy: The basics - Nigel Warburton]

What does the word "that" mean in the sentence? I find it too complex to understand.

Answer (score 2):

> it doesn’t follow from the fact that, from amongst all those millions of losing tickets, your winning ticket was chosen that this must have been the result of something more than a random selection.

The basic structure here is

> It doesn't follow from (some circumstance) that (some consequence).

This is a fairly common idiom, introduced by "follow from" where *that* is used to separate the precondition from the consequence.

It's made somewhat hard to follow because the circumstance part is a compound phrase, but otherwise it's a straightforward use of the word *follow*.